# Laravel LoginController condition don't work everytime

Tags: laravel

I want to block the login access to some users who are in blocked structures , it's working the first time but when i go back to the navigator and i try again to login the user can access to the application. i don't know why .. any idea ?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}


protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{

    $blacklist = Structure::where('blocked' , '=' , 1)->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $structure_id = $user->structure->id;


    if(in_array($structure_id,$blacklist)){

        return redirect('compte-bloque');

    }else{

        return redirect('/home');

    }
}
```

Comment: Just an observation, but `->pluck()` returns a `Collection`, which has the `->contains()` method, so you could use `if($blacklist->contains($structure_id))` instead of converting to array then using `in_array`, as `->contains()` essentially does that for you.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you wanting to not allow these users to login at all or just not let them access certain areas of the site?

Comment: i want to not let them access to all the application

Comment: @TimLewis i tried your suggestion but still the same first time it's redirect well but the second time it redirect to "home"

Comment: My suggestion was just an efficiency/working with the framework thing; didn't expect it to fix your issue :P

Answer (score 0):

The `authenticated` method is called after the user has been logged in to the site so you will need to log them out again.

Also, you can probably simplify you're logic quite a bit here. Assuming that `Structure` is the same model as `$user->structure` you should be able to do:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->structure->blocked) {

        auth()->logout();

        return redirect('compte-bloque');
    } 
}
```

Comment: if i put auth()->logout(); the user never see the view 'compte-bloque'; your method work but i would like to keep the view. should i use auth()->logout(); as facade in the view ?

Comment: or maybe do you know where the login is called before authenticated, i can put this condition inside maybe

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Does that user need to be logged in to see `compte-bloque`??

Comment: @MathieuMourareau If the user doesn't have to be logged in to `compte-bloque` then I don't see a reason why they wouldn't be able to be redirected to `compte-bloque`.  What's actually happening after they get logged out in this way?

Comment: i  just need to check igf the user who want to loggin is attach to a blocked structure then if it's the case i return "compte-bloque". actually if i use auth()->logout; return redirect('compte-bloquer'), the user stay at the login page after trying to login to the app. @RossWilson

Comment: @MathieuMourareau That would lead me to believe that the `compte-bloquer` route is under the auth middleware. If you don't want to log them out then simply remove the `auth()->logout();` line.